# Convert webpages into webapps

Tags: nix, nixos

Due to laziness, I created some web pages that I use daily as a webapp using Chrome's "Create Shortcut" functionality. This is more convenient because I can see them in a single window or on my task bar as an app.

This is a manual step and I would like to have this automated in my configuration.nix or home.nix so that I can have these apps on all of my machines.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not sure if it is the same, but this is how I've learned to create a shortcut. It's just a package, not a generic module, but I think you could use it as an example for how such a module can construct web shortcuts. https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/156169

Comment: Maybe you should try converting them to an electron app.